# How to animate a single line text view on text append

Tags: android, animation, textview

I have a text view with the following layout parameters:

```
        android:gravity="end"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
```

Normally the text grows off the layout and only the last part is visible, then some text is appended by a word or two. But from a user point of view, it not always recognizable that new text was appended, because the single line is always filled with text. So it's hard for the eye to catch.

I want to have a two step animation at text append:
1# the original text slide out a little
2# the appended content slides in at the same time

So as if the extra text is added off the layout, then the animation starts and slides it in, till the new content is re-aligned once more.

All tips or code snippets are welcomed ;-)

Comment: not 100% on this, but can you check if programmatically settings text on a TextView triggers a TextWatcher?

Comment: As far as I understand, textWatchers checks TextEdit while the user is entering text. This is not my case. I have a TextView where the app appends one or two words every couple of seconds .. I just need to show the new words in a smooth way.